# please check my Java homework, dialog boxes and variable type mismatches

Tags: java

The title says this is homework, I have been beating my head into the wall for hours, so please help. It works fine, at least the math part does, I work the conversion it worked just fine. I went to change the output dialog box to list what the ending unit was, instead of just listing the variable e.g. your lbs is the end. And not to allow negative starting weights.

Now I can't get the dialog box to not give me an error. (Lines 145 -148)  I put in a sample dialog box using the Return option that doesn't work, but if I set it to a variable in my case test, it will work fine. He gave us starting code, I recopied his original code and that doesn't work. The next error I get is I wrote a method that takes two doubles and a char. When I call the function I pass it two doubles and a char it says it can't convert a string (Line 255).

This has been frustrating I over engineered this and now to have it not work is killing me. I don't understand how I can copy his original code in and it no longer works. Dialog boxes confuse me but I think I understand them.

```
return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(A)(null(B), display(C),0,1);
```

A is the call of the for the box what type
B is the object type my understanding its always call
C is the string, text message of the box
The last two got to do with the the icon and button displayed.

He got us started on eclipse, which said I had error in code where there none, I spent hours looking at them, they went away once I reloaded my code.

Please any thing would be helpful, but an example or corrected code (I know that is a lot) with explanations on why there are correct would be helpful. My husband knows java but not dialog boxes, so he can't help. And the method call looks right to both of us.

```
    /* 
 * Uses: methods, dialog boxes, and a menu to convert weights
 * 
 */

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class WeightCon {
    char choices, choicee;
public static char menu() {
    char choice;
    int typeNum = 3;
    boolean OK;
    String prompt, results, title;
    prompt = "Choose Starting Unit\n";
    prompt += "A. Pounds\n";
    prompt += "B. Kilograms\n";
    prompt += "C. Stones\n";
    prompt += "D. ounces\n";
    prompt += "E. Netons\n";
    prompt += "F.Grams\n";
    prompt += "\n\nEnter the letter of your choice:";
    title = "Weights";

    do {
        results = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,prompt,title, typeNum);
        choice = results.toUpperCase().charAt(0);
    
        if(choice >= 'A' && choice <= 'F') {
            OK = true;
        }
        else {
            OK = false;
            title = "Not Valid Input!";
            typeNum = 0;
        }
    }while(! OK);
    
    return choice;
    
}
    
public static double LbstoKG(double k) {
        return k * 0.453592;
    }

public static double KtoLBS(double L) {
    return L / 0.453592;
}

public static double LbstoStone(double S) {
    return S / 14;
    
}
public static double LBStoOunce(double O) {
    return O / .0625;

}
public static double LbstoNewton(double N) {
    return N * 4.4482216282509;
}

public static double LBStoGarm(double G) {
    return G / 0.00220462 ;
}

public static double KtoL(double L) {
return L / 0.453592;
}

public static double stoneToLbs(double L) {
return L * 14;

}
public static double ounceToLBS(double L) {
return L * .0625;

}
public static double NewtonToLBS(double L) {
return L / 4.4482216282509;
}

public static double GramtoLBS(double L) {
return L * 0.00220462 ;
}
//public static double 

    
    public static double getDouble(String prompt) {
        boolean OK;
        double val=0;
        String temp, title = "Enter a double value";
        int typeNum = 3;
        
        do {
            
            OK = true;
            temp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, prompt, title, typeNum);
            try {
                val = Double.parseDouble(temp);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                OK = false;
                title = "Error! Invalid input. Must be a double value";
                typeNum = 0;
            }
            try {
                val = Double.parseDouble(temp);
            
            }
            catch(Exception b) {
            if( val < 0) {
                title = "Error! Invalid input. Must be a positive double value";
                typeNum = 0;
            
            }
        }while(! OK);
        }while(! OK);
        
        return val;
        
    }
    
    public static String outputResults(double start, double end, char choices){

        int test;
    String end1;
        if(choices == 'A') {
            end1 = "Your end weight is the following  pounds: ";
        } else if (choices == 'B') {
            end1 = " Your end weight is the following  kilograms: ";
        } else if (choices == 'C') {
            end1 = " Your end weight is the following  stones: ";
        } else if (choices == 'D') {
                end1 = " Your end weight is the following  ounces: ";   
        } else if (choices == 'E') {
                end1 = " Your end weight is the following  newtons: ";
        } else if (choices == 'F') {
                end1 = " Your end weight is the following  grams: ";
        } else {end1 = " ERROR ERROR UNDEFINDED ERROR PLEASE CONSOLT DOCUMENTATION";}
        
        String endreal = String.valueOf(end);
        String display = ""  + end1 + endreal;
         //int input = 
        test = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, display,0,1);
        test = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, display);
        return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, display);
        return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, display,0,1);
        }
        //display += "Do again?";
        
        //return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"test",0,1);
        //return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,display,0,1);}}
    //return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "test",0,1);}}
    //}
//  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        double get;
        double lbs=0,ounce=0,kgs=0, stone=0,newton=0,gram=0 ;
        double temp,start, end;
        char choice, choices;
        int button;
        //String end1;
        start =-99;
        end = -999; 
        get = 0;
        temp = 0;
        
        do {
            choice = menu();
            choices = choice;
            
            switch(choice) {
            case 'A':
                
                get =  getDouble("Enter pounds : ");
                lbs = get;
                start = get; //LbstoKG(get);
                temp = kgs;
                break;
            case 'B': 
                get = getDouble("Enter kilograms : ");
                kgs = get;
                start = KtoL(get);
                temp = lbs;
                break;
            case 'C':
                get = getDouble("Enter Stones : ");
                stone = get;
                start = stoneToLbs(get);
                temp = lbs;
                break;
            case 'D':
                ounce = getDouble("Enter Ounces : ");
                start = ounceToLBS(get);
                temp = lbs;
                break;
            case 'E':
                get= getDouble("Enter Newtons : ");
                newton = get;
                start = NewtonToLBS(get);
                temp = lbs;
                break;
            case 'F':
                get = getDouble("Enter grams : ");
                gram = get;
                start = GramtoLBS(get);
                temp = lbs;
                
                break;
            }
            
            
            //button = outputResults(get,get);
        //} while(button == 0);
    //  do {
            choice = menu();
            switch(choice) {
            case 'A':
                
                //get =  getDouble("Enter pounds : ");
                //lbs = getDouble("Enter pounds : ");
                //kgs = get;
                end = start;
                break;
            case 'B': 
                //get = getDouble("Enter kilograms : ");
                end = LbstoKG(start);
                break;
            case 'C':
                //get = getDouble("Enter Stones : ");
                //stone = get;
                end = LbstoStone(start);
                break;
            case 'D':
                //ounce = getDouble("Enter Ounces : ");
                end = LBStoOunce(start);
                break;
            case 'E':
                //get= getDouble("Enter Newtons : ");
                end = LbstoNewton(start);
                System.out.printf("Hello");
                break;
            case 'F':
                //get = getDouble("Enter grams : ");
                end = LBStoGarm(start);
            
                
                break;
            }
            
            
            button = outputResults(end,start,choice);
        } while(button == 0);
        
}}
```

Comment: If you want someone to review your code, you should post it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, not here.

Comment: @Andreas: Codereview is for code that works.  The OP's code doesn't work.

Comment: *"... give me an error. (Lines 145 -148)"* (Steinbeck, 1) Please give a clear error statement directly from your compiler, and add pointers as to show where these lines actually are.

Answer (score -1):

After copying and pasting your code into my compiler, there were multiple errors.

First Mistake in `outputResults()`: Remove the 0, and the 1.

```
The method showConfirmDialog(Component, Object, String, int) in the type JOptionPane 
is not applicable for the arguments (null, String, int, int)
Line: 
test = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, display,0,1);
Correction:
test = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, display);
```

Second and Third Mistake also in `outputResults()`: You cannot return two objects. Also, your method returns a String.

```
return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, display);
return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, display,0,1); // 0, 1 again.
// The second return statement is dead code, and this also makes the first mistake again
```

```
Your method returns a String.
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, display); returns an int.
So in your method returning a String, if you return an int instead, it will be a compiler error. For example:
... String outputResults(...){
    return JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, display);
}
1 quick fix: change return type to int (method: String outputResults(double, double, char))
```

Fourth Mistake in `main()`: Fix your Third Mistake and ignore this fix.

```
int button = ...;
...
button = outputResults(end,start,choice); // Returns String, but button is an int
// Change button to a string?
// Integer.parseInt(outputResults(end,start,choice)); ?
```

Comment: I would like to know who downvoted my answer, and why, as it is meant to help debug, and it does help debug OP's code.